# Ubuntu server 14.04 openstack glance image download issue

Tags: openstack

When I run the following command:

```
wget http://cdn.download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.3/cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img
```

output is:

```
Connected,
Http request sent awaiting response : 404 not found..
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Have you tried correcting the address? http://cdn.download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.3 doesn't appear to exist so obtaining a file in that non-existent directory is impossible. Try wget with a known good link to verify that it works properly, verify links in your browser.

Comment: You may find this useful as well: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

Comment: can anyone please send me any working link to download cirros related img file

Comment: https://download.cirros-cloud.net/ - note that the security certificate is invalid.

Comment: one more problem, with in /tmp/images : glance image-create command output is : expecting os name, os user name , password , tenant name etc

Comment: askubuntu is a Q & A site not a forum.  Please research new questions, and if you don't find an answer post a new question using the button in the upper right corner of the page. Thank you

Comment: I know that, but due to my question limit exceeded, that's why i asked here only.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=+expecting+os+name%2C+os+user+name+%2C+password+%2C+tenant+name&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/cirros (which http://cirros-cloud.net/ redirects to) says to "download images for cirros at http://download.cirros-cloud.net/". You can find the image you wish to download there, which should be http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.3/cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img.

Comment: one more problem, with in /tmp/images : glance image-create command output is : expecting os name, os user name , password , tenant name etc

Comment: The command is probably asking for those missing arguments. You need to provide those.

Comment: how to provide those, because i have set the environment variable in admin-openrc.sh, glance-resgistry, glance api etc. but due to i have changes the directory to tmp/images. i dont know how to do that

Comment: That question is better answered in a separate question. You mentioned hitting the question limit, so you might have more luck searching on the Internet for answers to your question.

Comment: i am not getting the favourable answer. if you can help out me here, that 's would be better as a help. Thank you

Comment: http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/cli_manage_images.html#glance_add_image

Comment: /tmp/images : glance image-create command output is : expecting os name, os user name , password , tenant name, to provide those, because i have set the environment variable in admin-openrc.sh, glance-resgistry, glance api etc. but due to i have changes the directory to tmp/images. i dont know how to do that ...this is the problem

Comment: As @ElderGeek has previously mentioned, this is not a forum, and you should attempt to research to solve your question, or create a new question to ask about this. If you do not have enough reputation points, you should [find a way to earn more](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score -1):

Download the newer version:

```
wget http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.4/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img
```